# Add/Delete input fields that have dynamic values with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have dynamic input fields inside the form. Data is being pulled from mysql table to populate each input field. I am using jquery to give the user the ability to add more input fields or to delete an input field. The `delete` button shows disabled and does not allow me to delete an entry. The `delete` is only to be disabled if there is less than two `.clonedSection` displaying inside the form. How can I fix this error? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/select_test.php)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedSection').length;
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1);

        var newSection = $('#pq_entry_' + num).clone().attr('id', 'pq_entry_' + newNum);
        newSection.children(':first').children(':first').attr('id', 'person_fname_' + newNum).attr('name', 'person_fname_' + newNum).attr('placeholder', 'Person #' + newNum + ' First Name');
        newSection.children(':nth-child(2)').children(':first').attr('id', 'person_lname_' + newNum).attr('name', 'person_lname_' + newNum); 
        newSection.children(':nth-child(3)').children(':first').attr('id', 'person_email_' + newNum).attr('name', 'person_email_' + newNum); 
        newSection.children(':nth-child(4)').children(':first').attr('id', 'person_phone_' + newNum).attr('name', 'person_phone_' + newNum); 
        newSection.children(':nth-child(5)').children(':first').attr('id', 'person_fax_' + newNum).attr('name', 'person_fax_' + newNum); 
        newSection.children(':nth-child(6)').children(':first').attr('id', 'person_contact_' + newNum).attr('name', 'person_contact_' + newNum);  
        newSection.children(':nth-child(7)').children(':first').attr('id', 'person_instructor_' + newNum).attr('name', 'person_instructor_' + newNum);
        newSection.insertAfter('#pq_entry_' + num).last();

        $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', '');

        if (newNum == 5) $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedSection').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        $('#pq_entry_' + num).remove(); // remove the last element

        // enable the "add" button
        $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', '');

        // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
        if (num - 1 == 1) $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
});
//http://jsfiddle.net/34rYv/87/
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">

 <?php
//Database connection
try {
    $db_con = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $db_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
} 
//Populate the input fields with data from mysql table 
$db_select3  = $db_con->prepare("
SELECT     a.name, 
           a.academy_id,
           p.contact_role,
           p.instructor_role,
           p.first_name,
           p.last_name,
           p.person_email,
           p.person_phone,
           p.person_fax
    FROM academy a
    LEFT JOIN person p ON a.academy_id = p.academy_id
    WHERE a.academy_id = 15
");
if (!$db_select3) return false;
if (!$db_select3->execute()) return false;
    $results3 = $db_select3->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (empty($results3)) return false;
    $result3 = '';
echo "<strong>Personel Information:</strong>";
$s = 1;
foreach ($results3 as $value3){ 
    echo "<ul id=\"pq_entry_".$s."\" class=\"clonedSection\">";
    echo "<li><input id=\"person_fname_".$s."\" name=\"person_fname_".$s."\" placeholder=\"Person #1 - First Name\" type=\"text\" value='" . $value3['first_name'] ."'/></li>";
    echo "<li><input id=\"person_lname_".$s."\" name=\"person_lname_".$s."\" placeholder=\"Last Name\" type=\"text\" value='" . $value3['last_name'] ."'/></li>";
    echo "<li><input id=\"person_email_".$s."\" name=\"person_email_".$s."\" placeholder=\"Email\" type=\"text\" value='" . $value3['person_email'] ."'/></li>";
    echo "<li><input id=\"person_phone_".$s."\" name=\"person_phone_".$s."\" placeholder=\"Phone\" type=\"text\" value='" . $value3['person_phone'] ."'/></li>";
    echo "<li><input id=\"person_fax_".$s."\" name=\"person_fax_".$s."\" placeholder=\"Fax\" type=\"text\" value='" . $value3['person_fax'] ."'/></li>";
    echo "</ul>";
$s++;   
}   
echo "<input type='button' id='btnAdd' value='add another Person' />
<input type='button' id='btnDel' value='delete Delete' />";

?>
```

Comment: This is a cool device, I'll take a look at it, but please get rid of all those annoying popus in the example. YOUR APP WORKS!?!?!?

Comment: @hanzo2001 Sorry about the ads. Its free hosting. Well the delete button is not working properly.

Comment: your example is functional on my browser. The delete button is awkwardly deactivated only on page load. When you add one person it becomes active and then it works as intended

Comment: @hanzo2001 Yes, that awkward deactivation is what I am trying to get rid of.

Comment: I'll take the liberty of rewriting part of your javascript/jQuery, I hope you don't mind

Comment: @hanzo2001 feel free to do so :). http://jsfiddle.net/34rYv/87/

Comment: I'm sorry to keep bugging you but your code is kinda of all messy, this will take a while

Comment: @hanzo2001 Yes I agree with you. I need to follow a better coding standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is a quick solution

the last line of your javascript is

```
$('#btnDel').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

this means that this will be executed on page load, no matter the number of cloned sections. The solution would be either to

- put it in an `if` clause and check the initial `clonedSection Nodes`
- rewrite this mess and have it more clear

Your call. I'm currently rewriting the spaghetti you have there but if this suits you then I guess that's that.

Any questions, please ask

#### your javascript

this is not tested, it may not work but its intention is educational. ***Plus***, half of all the code is to accomodate this strange way of formatting your html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var
    uniqueNum = 0,
    maxNumOfSections = 5,
    fields = ['fname','lname','email','phone','fax','contact','instructor'],
    container = $('.clonedSection').parent(),
    btnDelete = $('#btnDel'),
    btnAppend = $('#btnAdd'),
    onAdd,
    onDelete,
    fnInputCreator,
    fnInputSet,
    fnList;
  // make formatted inputs
  fnInputCreator = function (name) {
    var extra = name === 'fname' ? 'placeholder="Person #'+uniqueNum+' First Name"' : '';
    return '<li><input type="text" id="'+name+'" name="'+name+'"'+extra+' /></li>';
  };
  // make a set of inputs
  fnInputSet = function () {
    var r = '';
    fields.forEach(function(v){r += fnInputCreator('person_'+v+'_'+uniqueNum);});
    return r;
  };
  // make the input container
  fnList = function () {
    return '<ul id="pq_entry_'+uniqueNum+'" class="clonedSection">'+fnInputSet()+'</ul>';
  };
  // onClick event
  onAdd = function () {
    container.append(fnList());
    uniqueNum++;
    btnDelete.prop('disabled',false);
    if (uniqueNum === maxNumOfSections) btnAppend.prop('disabled',true);
  };
  // onClick event
  onDelete = function () {
    container.last().remove();
    btnAppend.prop('disabled',false);
    uniqueNum--;
    if (uniqueNum === 1) btnDelete.prop('disabled',true);
  };
  // add listeners
  btnAppend.click(onAdd);
  btnDelete.click(onDelete);
  // disable if only one left
  if (container.children().length < 2) btnDelete.prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Please write nice javascript, if you want to follow some good guidelines check out **Crockford**

Comment: Alright will do so! Also could you post in your answer your rewrite. Thank you for your dedicated help.